# c# calls c++ function

Tags: c#, c++

I tried to use

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
```

and `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`

to get the c++ function pointer from c++ library in c# project.

Everything seems okay, i can get non-zero `IntPtr` in both `GetProcAddress` and `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

However, when I invoke the function, it would return `IntPtr.Zero`.

When I debugging in Visual Studio Hosting, the function invokes successfully without any problems. However, when I run the program after build without Visual studio hosting, the function return `IntPtr.Zero`.

===========================================================================

> What is the value of hModule when you run outside the debugger?

value after LoadLibrary: 252182528

value after GetProcAddress: 252326960

> Are you sure you are calling a method in a c++ class or just a straight up function? If it's the latter just use [DllImport] rather than mucking about with GetProcAddress

I am calling a class in C++, invoking a method in c++ to get an instance of it.

> Please provide actual Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - it is hard to reason why code does not behave the way you like without seeing it.

Here it is

```
public class NativeMethod
{
    private static ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void RtlMoveMemory(ref IntPtr dst, IntPtr src, int size);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("WS2_32.DLL")]
    public static extern int WSAStartup(int wVersionRequested, IntPtr lpWsaData);

    [DllImport("WS2_32.DLL")]
    public static extern int WSACleanup();

    public static void LoadFunction<T>(string dllPath, string functionName) 
    {
        var hModule = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
        var functionAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
        Delegate oFunc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionAddress, typeof(T));
        IntPtr oFuncRtn = oFunc.DynamicInvoke();
        if(oFuncRtn == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception(" failed.");
    }        
}
```

Comment: What is the value of hModule when you run outside the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling a method in a c++ class or just a straight up _function_?  If it's the latter just use `[DllImport]` rather than mucking about with `GetProcAddress`

Comment: Please provide actual [MCVE] - it is hard to reason why code does not behave the way you like without seeing it.

Comment: You do not say what functionName you are passing to `LoadFunction`. One thing to check for is the calling convention. Another avenue of research is that the call could be failing for reasons unrelated to the function pointer -> delegate conversion.

Comment: But one strange thing is that i can invoke the function successfully under Visual Studio hosting, however, it cannot when i run the compiled program